# Link not working after menuid being applied?

Tags: joomla-4.x

I'm writing a new extension in Joomla4.  When I add an item to my menu and click on the link that is generated on the main menu, it keeps saying the page cannot be found, but if I change the number after the `Itemid=` to anything else or add a `?` to the end it works.  Does anyone know why the link with the menu id is not working?

- https://ibb.co/2tjhgKf with site defaulted ItemId
- https://ibb.co/tccpMdF after removing ItemId, changing the number, or adding ? to end

Comment: Try turning off the Debug Language in Global Configuration and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: Hey Irata, I had tried that and it was still getting the same issue.

Comment: Is this still an issue for you?  Looking at the first screen print listed shows you are in a Model for for extension but the left side of the image is missing but it appears you are then somehow trying to display a page from a Model. You might need to share some more details of your code or use a debugger to step through your code to find out more.

Comment: Hey Irata, still an issue